# How to put GUI in joptionpane?

Tags: user-interface, joptionpane

How to add GUI in this JOPTIONPANE?

```
private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
public static final String[] Vehicle = { "Car","Motorcycle" };

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String userVehicleType;
    String userInputHours;
    String userInput;
    int hoursPark;
    int totalHours;
    double userPayment=0;
    double balance=0;
    double addHours;
    double totalAmount=0;
    Integer ParkHours;
    int newPayment;
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Welcome to Wangsa Walk Ticket " );
  
    do{
        
    
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    String[] choice = new String[2];
    choice[0] = "Car";
    choice[1] = "Motocycle";
        int showOptionDialog = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(),"What Type of vehicle your using?","Title", 0,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choice,null);
    
      switch(showOptionDialog){
        case 0:
            
    
    userInputHours= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("how long do you park?");
    hoursPark= Integer.parseInt(userInputHours);
    
    if (hoursPark==2){
       
        totalAmount=2;
        userInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your fee is RM 2.00. "+
                "Please insert your money (RM)");
        userPayment= Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    
        balance= userPayment - 2;
    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your balance is RM " +df.format(balance));
        break;
    }
    
    else if (hoursPark>2&&hoursPark!=24){
        
        totalAmount=(hoursPark*1)+ 2;
        
        
        userInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Your fee is RM "+df.format(totalAmount)+
                ". Please insert your money (RM)");
        userPayment= Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        
        balance= userPayment - totalAmount;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your balance is RM " +df.format(balance));
        break;
        
    }
    
    else if (hoursPark==24){
        
        totalAmount=30;
        userInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your parking fee is RM 30.00. "+ 
                "Please insert your money (RM)");
        userPayment= Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        
        balance= userPayment-30;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your balance is RM " +df.format(balance));
        break;
        
    }
        
        
        case 1:
            
            
    userInputHours= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input your parking hours");
    hoursPark= Integer.parseInt(userInputHours);
    
    if (hoursPark==1){
       
        totalAmount=1;
        userInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your fee is RM 1.00. "+
                "Please insert your money (RM)");
        userPayment= Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    
        balance= userPayment - 1;
    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your balance is RM " +df.format(balance));
        break;
    }
    
    else if (hoursPark>=2){
        
        addHours=(hoursPark-1)*0.5;
        totalAmount= addHours+1;
        
        userInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your fee is RM "+df.format(totalAmount)+
                ". Please insert your payment (RM)");
        userPayment= Integer.parseInt(userInput);
        
        balance= userPayment - totalAmount;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your balance is RM " +df.format(balance));
        break;
        
    }
    }
    
    String Receipt = "Your parking fees is RM "+df.format(totalAmount)+". the amount you pay is RM "
            +df.format(userPayment)+". Your balance is RM "+df.format(balance)+ 
            ".\n Thank you, Please come again.";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, Receipt );

    
    String anotherpayment = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Would you like to make another payment?\n1.Yes\n2.No",
               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    newPayment = Integer.parseInt(anotherpayment);

    }while(newPayment==1);
    
    System.exit(0);
```

}
}`

Comment: Please be more descriptive, if you want some help. I have to read all your code just to understand your question.

Comment: Also, what type of gui do you want? So far the code does work and does have a gui.